# IBAction that create a new UIViewController that is identical to the current one

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

I am developing a simple drawing app that saves the user's change (paint) then allow the user to have a new empty page when clicking on "New Page" button.
I'm facing a problem while trying to create a new page..

I'm using the single view template and currently my app contains only one ViewController. I want a new ViewController that is identical to the current one (but without the user's change (the user paint)) to be generated automatically when clicking on the "new page" button.

It is kind of similar to the notepad app, except that it doesn't use a tableView. I've looked over a lot of NotePad app source code, but I can't find what I actually need!

I hope you can help

thanks in advance

Comment: What happens to the old 'page'? Can you just clear the drawing from the view? Or how will you navigate between the 'pages'?

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: the changes in the old page are saved. Yes I can code that but this is not the point of my app, you see I want to create something like a book that contains number of pages according to the user preference. about the navigation, the main page is the first, then the first one the user create is the second… etc.

Comment: UIPageViewController may help you

Comment: yes I'm using story board.. thanks, I'll check the UIPageViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
- (IBAction)newPagePressed
{
    UIViewController *newVC = [[self class] alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController setViewCntrollers:@[newVC]];
}
```

you'll need to use UINavigationController to achieve it, otherwise you can try:

```
- (IBAction)newPagePressed
{
    MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIViewController *newVC = [[self class] alloc] init];
    appDelegate.rootViewController = newVC;
}
```

Comment: ok I think this is kind of working! a new page actually appear, but it's completely empty.. It only contains the UINavigationController bar. Is it possible to make other elements (such as labels, buttons..etc) appear as well in the new views?